# Parsing XML User Inputted Variables with Swift

Tags: xml, swift

I am trying to parse an XML document to get the user inputted variables and save these as variables in swift. The examples I have seen online use NSXMLParser with hard coded values.

How would you parse the user inputted variables? Here is an example of the variables that I would need to parse:

**EDIT**: Similar to the Watson Dialog XML

```
    <folder label="Main">
        <output>
            <prompt selectionType="RANDOM">
                <item>Hello, welcome to Mike’s Pizza what keywords do you want</item>
            </prompt>
            <goto ref="getUserInput_2449614"/>
        </output>
        <getUserInput id="getUserInput_2449614">
            <search ref="folder_2449611"/>
            <default>
                <output>
                    <prompt selectionType="RANDOM">
                        <item>I am sorry, I did not understand your question. Please try asking another one.</item>
                    </prompt>
                </output>
            </default>
        </getUserInput>
    </folder>
    <folder label="Library">
        <folder label="Live Content" id="folder_2449611">
            <input>
                <grammar>
                    <item>What type of keywords do you have?</item>
                    <item>$ What type of keywords do you have?</item>
                    <item>$ list of keywords</item>
                    <item>What * keywords * have</item>
                    <item>$ list keywords * available</item>
                    <item>$ what keywords do you have</item>
                </grammar>
                <output>
                    <prompt selectionType="RANDOM">
                        <item>We have Pepperoni, Mushrooms, and Sausage</item>
                    </prompt>
                    <getUserInput>
                        <input id="userInput" type="TEXT"> 
                            <grammar>
                                <item>*</item>
                            </grammar>
                            <output>
                                <prompt/>
                                <action varName="topping" operator="SET_TO_USER_INPUT"/>
                                <output>
                                    <prompt>
                                        <item>you just ordered this topping: {topping}</item>
                                    </prompt>
                                </output>
                            </output>
                        </input>
                    </getUserInput>
                </output>
            </input>
        </folder>
    </folder>
    <constants>
        <var_folder name="Home"/>
    </constants>
    <variables>
        <var_folder name="Home">
            <var id="topping" name="topping" type="TEXT"/>
        </var_folder>
    </variables>
```

Comment: (1) iOS or OS X? (2) the sample input is not well-formed XML. (3) what's your expected output?

Comment: @CodeDifferent (1) iOS (2) Edited the XML - similar to the Watson Dialog (3) I'm looking to save the topping variable as a variable in Swift. The actual application uses the Watson Service to have a conversation with the user but I want a way to store these variables in the code.